# Simple Directional Lighting for Particles

Tags: glsl, fragment-shader, particle-system

I have a particle system in a cylinder shape.  **How can I "light" half of it and have it smoothly transition to the darker color while having control over the max brightness of the light color?**

This does what I want, **but when I change the radius of the cylinder, the lightest color of the lighter** side gets lighter because the particle position is getting further away from 0..

```
varying vec3 fpDL;  <-- incoming particle position

vec3 objPos = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
float fragLS = objPos.x + fpDL.x;
vec3 pColor = vec3(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
float lightStrength = 0.001;
vec3 result = pColor * fragLS * lightStrength;
gl_FragColor = vec4(result, opacity);
```

I'm obviously missing some factors to this equation..

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do what I asked..

```
varying vec3 fpDL;  <-- incoming particle position

vec3 pColor = vec3(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
vec3 lColor = vec3(0.6, 0.6, 0.6);
float lStrength = 1.0;

vec3 objPos = vec3(0.0, fpDL.y, 0.0);
vec3 fragDir = normalize(fpDL - objPos); 
vec3 dirLight = clamp(fragDir * lStrength, 0.0, lStrength) ;
vec3 result = pColor + (dirLight.x * lColor);

gl_FragColor = vec4(result, opacity);
```